# How to autoload an xml file every 30 seconds?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, xml-parsing

Currently I have a parser.php which loads an xml file and inserts new data from the xml file into a mysql database. How would I go about refreshing this php file every 30 seconds so my mysql table always has fresh data? I think I could use short-polling to do this, but I'm guessing this is not the most efficient of options.

Thanks in advance

Comment: problem with a cron job is that I'd be limited to 1minute intervals

Comment: `Cron` or `setInterval`. Depends on how much you want to tax your server.

Comment: Cron jobs are unfortunately not useful for intervals bellow one minute.

Comment: use `sleep()` in php to run function again after 30 seconds in a 1 minute interval cron

Comment: would that not introduce sliding window problems

Comment: I'd have to change the rest of my code though :(

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-PHP solution which will require you to have shell (SSH) access in order to run the script, however you can also run it through PHP with **[exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)** if you want to. Shared hosting environments might present a challenge for this approach but as long as you can execute scripts under your user credentials you should have no problems running it.

First you will need to create a bash script with the following content and save it (I'll use the name `parser.sh` for the purpose of this example). You can then adjust the timeout in the `sleep 30` line if you want to.

```
#!/bin/sh  
while true
  do
    php parser.php
    sleep 30
  done
```

In order to run the script you'll need to give it execute permissions.

```
chmod +x parser.sh
```

Now you can use the **[nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)** command with the ampersand (&) argument to ensure that the script will run in the background even when a termination signal is sent after, lets say, closing the shell (SSH). **The ampersand is important**!

```
nohup ./parser.sh &
```

Now you can use `top` or `ps aux | grep parser` to ensure that the script is running. As I already said before you can also use PHP `exec()` to start the process but shell is still the preferred and most reliable way to do this.

If you want to stop the background process which executes your script then you'll simply have to kill it. Just use `ps aux | grep parser` to find out the PID of the parser process (its in the second column to the left) and use it with the **[kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill)** command.

```
kill 4183
```

Comment: Its is. Some things are simply not meant to be implemented through PHP and that's where you'll learn to love bash scripting.

Comment: what would I save this script as on my server (sorry how nooby I am!)

Comment: is the file extension .sh ?

Comment: bash is not picky so you are not required to use the `.sh` extension for bash scripts. However, using it is never a bad idea. I'll add it to avoid confusion.

Comment: great, so it should be working by implementing what you done above :)

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to be working correctly, I must be doing something wrong

Comment: it doesn't seem to be because my php is not getting executed. However I could be doing it completely wrong!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21185/discussion-between-andrew-charlton-and-holodoc)

Comment: could we speak in chat? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a cronjob, but crons jobs runs every 1 minute or more.

Another way is to make a "daemon".

Very basic example:

```
<?php
while(true) {
   // check if 30 seconds has passed.
   // then execute some function...
};
?>
```

Then you need to execute this in your terminal:

```
$ php script.php &
```

This [link](http://devlog.info/2010/03/07/creating-daemons-in-php/) should help.

Greatings!

Comment: Yeah I'd need < 1 minute intervals. Make a daemon?

Comment: Yes, a daemon. A program that runs in backgrounds and is constantly doing something... in this case, fetching a xml every 30 seconds.

Comment: See my answer, theres a basic example.

Comment: thanks for this, I'm guessing & puts it in the background? How would I check if 30 seconds have passed

Comment: also, do are daemons memory intensive?

Comment: I just want to do what I said in my initial question :)